# Calling connection string from connection.cs file

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, 3-tier

Is there any problem with the code?? Its not working and throwing an exception object ref. not set to an instance of object..
The exception is in datageneric.cs file at codeline *string DbConnectionString = Connection.ConnectionString;*

connection.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Configuration;
    public static class Connection
    {
    private static string constr = "server=.;database=foood;";
        public static string ConnectionString
        {
    get
    {
        return constr;
    }
    set
    {
        constr = value;
    }
}
public static string ProviderName { get; set; }
static Connection()
{
    ConnectionString =WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
    ProviderName = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ProviderName;
}
    }
```

DataGeneric.cs

```
        public static DbCommand CreateCommand()
{
    DbCommand cmd=null;
    try
    {
        string DbConnectionString = Connection.ConnectionString;
        string DbProviderName = Connection.ProviderName;
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DbProviderName);
        DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = DbConnectionString;
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    return cmd;
}
```

GetData.cs

```
        public static DataTable gimmedata()
{
    string Query = "select * from [slider]";
    DbCommand cmd = DataGeneric.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = Query;
    DataTable dt = DataGeneric.ExecuteSelectCommand(cmd);
    return dt;
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GetData.gimmedata();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection class is `public static`. So to use its variables create it `object` in `DataGeneric.cs` and then access that class through that object.

```
Connection con = new Connection();

string DbConnectionString = con.ConnectionString;
```

Hope that works.